# IIS7 SMTP doesn't work. Mails stuck in "Badmail" folder

Tags: php, email, iis-7, smtp, windows-server-2008

i'm trying to implement the mail verification on my website. I've read the guides on the microsoft forums, and at the end of the steps they've told me to open 'cmd' and use this syntax

```
appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:smtp /from: string /deliveryMethod:network /network.port: int /network.defaultCredentials:True|False /network.host:string /network.userName:string /network.password:string
```

This got me an error regarding "/deliveryMethod:netword" but i ignored it because i didn't know what to do exactly.

So i tried a  method for veryfing the service by creating a txt with

The Source Email
 
The Destination 
Subject 
Body of the mail

then i pasted the file in the folder "C:\inetpub\mailroot\ **pickup**" but after that the mails stuck in the folder "C:\InetPub\MailRoot\ **BadMail**.

here is the php:

```
    $to = $fet2['mail'];
$subject = "Verifica Accoutn BoBBa Italia";
$txt = "<html>
<head>
<title>Verifica Account</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Ciao ".$fet2['username']."</p>
<p>Questa è un messaggio automatico del sistema. Per verificare il tuo account è semplicissimo, ti basta cliccare sul link qui sotto! .</p>
<p>Verifica il tuo account!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Link: clicca <a href='http://beta.bobbaitalia.it/verifico.php?token=".$token."'>QUI</a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>http://beta.bobbaitalia.it/verifico.php?token=".$token."</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>Grazie per aver scelto BoBBa Hotel Italia.</p>
<p>Non rispondere a questa email, è inattiva! </p>
<p><a href='http://beta.bobbaitalia.it/'>BoBBa Italia</a></p>
</body>
</html>";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: no reply <no-reply@bobbaitalia.it>";

$email=mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

Thanks in advance to everyone that will help!

Comment: *"This got me an error regarding "/deliveryMethod:netword""*...what was the error?

Comment: Well, somehow i managed to fix this problem, and i've another problem. 

The mail function in the php code doesn't work, i don't get any error or alert it just doesn't work. 
If i try to make a txt for trying the system manually , it sends the email though..